# message from webpage invalid postback or callback argument. event validation is enabled using

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My goal is to have the user be able to click the row and the row will be the selected row almost like having the select button but the entire row clickable to do the same thing

the error i get popups when i click the row, not when the webpage is loaded

this is the onrowdatabound portion i just added that causes the error

```
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            ' Get reference to button field in the gridview.
            Dim _singleClickButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(selectbutton, LinkButton)
            Dim _jsSingle As String = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "Select$" & Convert.ToString(e.Row.RowIndex))
            e.Row.Style("cursor") = "hand"
            e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = _jsSingle
        End If
```

This is my full on rowdatabound

```
 Protected Sub GridView6_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
            ' CHECK THE ROW TYPE HERE. ONLY EXECUTE ON DataRow     
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim date1 As Date
                date1 = Date.Now
                Dim date2 As Date

                Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("duedate"), Label)
                date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)
                Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)
                Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays

                If days <= 14 And days >= 0 Then
                    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
                    bluecount = bluecount + 1
                ElseIf days > 14 And days < 30 Then
                    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                    blackcount = blackcount + 1
                ElseIf days >= 30 Then
                    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                    greencount = greencount + 1
                ElseIf days < 0 Then
                    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                    redcount = redcount + 1
                End If


                Dim link As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1"), HyperLink)
                Dim id As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("id"), Label)



                Dim selectbutton As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.FindControl("linkbutton1"), LinkButton)


            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                ' Get reference to button field in the gridview.
                Dim _singleClickButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(selectbutton, LinkButton)
                Dim _jsSingle As String = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "Select$" & Convert.ToString(e.Row.RowIndex))
                e.Row.Style("cursor") = "hand"
                e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = _jsSingle
            End If


                link.NavigateUrl = "Default7.aspx?id=" + id.Text + "&uid=" + user1


                pduecount.Text = redcount
                next14count.Text = bluecount
                fteencount.Text = blackcount
                thirtycount.Text = greencount


            End If







        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set EnableEventValidation to False in Page directive of the aspx page (markup).